# Update : Move files from one folder to another based on file extension

Tags: java

**Situation:**

I am doing an automation where I have to download only CSV files from a set of files. And now i want to move only CSV files from one folder to another.

**Question:**

Can you please provide me code to delete files from the source folder as soon as the files are moved?

This is my code so far:

```
public class MyFilteredFileList {

    public static void main(String a[])

    {
        try {

        File source = new File("C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Downloads");
        File dest = new File("E:\\Query\\");

            FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest, new FileFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File pathname) 
                {
                    boolean source=pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");
                    if (source)
                        return true;
                         return false;
                   }

            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : But I am still facing a problem. It's downloading all the files at once and then deleting. But my requirement is something like - It should download first file -> move the downloaded file into another folder -> delete first downloaded file from download folder -> download second folder... and the process repeats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add pathname.deleteOnExit(); on accept method

```
@Override
 public boolean accept(File pathname) {
       boolean source = pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");

       if (source) {
           pathname.deleteOnExit();
           return true;
       }
   return false;
 }
```

whole code :

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Lenovo on 02/12/2018.
 */
public class FileMove {
    public static void main(String a[])

    {
        try {

            File source = new File("C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Downloads");
            File dest = new File("E:\\Query\\");

            FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest, new FileFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    boolean source = pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");

                    if (source) {
                        pathname.deleteOnExit();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184651/discussion-on-answer-by-flopcoder-update-move-files-from-one-folder-to-another).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move the file this way.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MyFilteredFileList {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        try {
            Files.move (Paths.get("C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Downloads\\file.txt"),
            Paths.get("E:\\Query\\file.txt"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to move only CSV files from set of files. Can you tell me how to delete files from source folder once they are moved.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this class and run :) Try setting the correct source and destination path if it doesn't work.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class MoveFile {

    private boolean moveFile(String source, String destination) throws IOException {
        Path srcPath = Paths.get(source);
        Path destPath = Paths.get(destination);
        System.out.println("Moving processed file to archive");
        Files.move(srcPath, destPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        return true;
    }

    private File[] getTheFilesWithExtension(String filePath, String ext) {

        File fileDir = new File(filePath);
        File[] files = fileDir.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext));
        return files;
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        {
            MoveFile moveFile = new MoveFile();
            String sourcePath = "C:\\\\Users\\\\sh370472\\\\Downloads";
            String destPath = "E:\\Query\\";
            String extension = ".csv";
            try {
                File[] files = moveFile.getTheFilesWithExtension(sourcePath, extension);
                for (File file : files){
                    moveFile.moveFile(file.getPath(),destPath+file.getName());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Its for Java 8 and above , for lower java version, you can update the lambda expression in getTheFilesWithExtension with the below code

```
private File[] getTheFilesWithExtension(String filePath, String ext) {

        File fileDir = new File(filePath);
        File[] files = fileDir.listFiles(
                new FilenameFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext);
                    }
                }
        );
        return files;
    }
```

Comment: It worked. But I am still facing a problem. It's downloading all the files at once and then deleting. But my requirement is something like - It should download first file -> move into another folder -> delete first file from download folder -> download second folder... and the process should repeat